# Why doesn’t pyautogui and directinput work in video game?

Tags: python, pyautogui, directinput

I’m trying to make a bot to play a video game for me, but neither pyautogui or directinput can make the character move in another direction. What is going on? Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Try running the python script as an administrator.